# $ in zf not recognized in command

Tags: zend-framework, installation

I have installed composer 
[image]

When I want to test it by running `$ composer serve` from [github.com/zendframework](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication)

I get error saying `$` is not recotgnized

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is not part of command. `$` usage mean you are using user terminal.
Same with `#`, it mean you are using `root` terminal.
So, just type `composer serve` in your terminal.

Comment: it did work i though `$` was part of the command i just copied it from the docs that i was following :)